# trouble solving the integral of $\cos(x^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

No, I really mean the integral of $\cos(x^2)$, not $[\cos(x)]^2$. Can the chain rule be applied here?

Comment: There is no expression for this in terms of elementary functions and normal techniques are useless. The best you can do is to apply Taylor series and integrate term-by-term. This is called a Fresnel integral and has lots of use in optics.

Comment: is this a definite or indefinite integral?

Comment: As an aside, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sin\big(x^2\big)~dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\cos\big(x^2\big)~dx = \sqrt{\frac\pi2}$$ This can be proven using [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) and the value of the [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Answer (score 2):

The function $\cos(x^2)$ doesn't have an elementary primitive. It can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions, I mean. You can only study the definite integral using numerical methods.

Comment: Well the latter claim is not really true. Taylor series are perfectly legitimate and far from a numerical method.

Answer (score 2):

Represent $\cos x^{2}$ as a power series by
$$
\cos x^{2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}x^{4k}}{\left(2k\right)!}.
$$
Then
$$
\int\cos x^{2}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}\int x^{4k}dx}{\left(2k\right)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}x^{4k+1}}{\left(2k\right)!\left(4k+1\right)}+C
$$
This is called the [Fresnel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).